# Mysql Join ,Group by and summation in single query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, left-join

I have 2 tables:

Table tms_invoices

```
id    load_id     company_name      amount
1       11          company1         40
2       11          company1         30
3       11          company2         40
4       12          company3         40
```

Table tms_loads

```
id    load_name     is_archived 
11       Load1          0
12       Load2          1
13       Load3          1
```

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix . 'tms_invoices';
$table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'tms_loads';
/**
* show invoices of loads that are not archived in loads table
*/
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $table_name1.* FROM $table_name1 LEFT JOIN $table_name2 ON $table_name1.load_id = $table_name2.id WHERE $table_name2.is_archived = '0'", ARRAY_A);
return $rows;
```

Above code is fetching all Invoices related to loads that are not archived.
But I want grouped by company_name and summation of amount column also.
**So output should be:**

```
load_id     company_name      amount
  11          company1         70
  11          company2         40
```

Anybody can do this for me?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `group by` :

```
SELECT load_id, company_name, sum(amount) as amount
FROM tms_invoices ti 
LEFT JOIN tms_loads tl ON ti.load_id = tl.id
WHERE tl.is_archived = '0'
GROUP BY load_id, company_name
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/yovraFX3)